# Mysql - same table copy date column from another column but decrease 3 days

Tags: mysql, date, sql-update

I have a simple table

```
id
name
date
date_send
```

I would like to, update field date_send corrisponding to the value inside field date, but decrese -3 days.

example:

```
date = 2018-12-25
```

it must save in date_send = 2018-12-22

many thanks.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DATE_SUB`:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET date_send = DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```